# How to check if one column in spark Dataset is empty?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

I have a **Dataset<Row> df**, and its content are shown below:

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 121.2 |  | A |
| 23.1 |  | B |

And I want to check if Column B is empty.

I think I can use this to check whether it is empty:

```
Dataset<Row> checkDf = df.select("Column B");
Boolean isEmpty = checkDf.isEmpty();
```

But I want to know if there is a more efficient way.

Thank you.

Comment: are you using spark with python ? or scala ? you might be able to use function isNull() to create a boolean expression if that's what you need.

Comment: Method `isEmpty` return true if Dataset has no rows; method is not related to column values.

Comment: I use spark with Java, and you guys tell me to use function isNull(), I will try it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dataset can be filtered for not null values, and emptiness checked, on Scala:

```
val isColumnBEmpty = checkDf.where(col("Column B").isNotNull).isEmpty
```